# Why can't I edit my post?

Tags: support, edits

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113223/how-do-i-plot-data-from-two-different-dataframes), and now I cannot edit it. I was initially unable to successfully post as I kept getting the indent error until I wrapped my table in a code block. Someone edited my post and fixed the table formatting by removing the code blocks around the tables, and now I am getting the indent error again when I try to edit my post. I disabled my ad-block plugins and tried different browsers with no success.

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot figure why am getting "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251183/cannot-figure-why-am-getting-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-prop)

Comment: Can confirm that it's the multiple `+` in the table that is triggering the error. How was the person that edited my post able to circumvent the code formatting detection?