# Recent flood of very low quality questions and non-questions with the Python tag today - what is going on?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, new-users, spam

I am wondering if Stack Overflow has been compromised by spammers. Within a few minutes, I have flagged a lot of questions which are either **non-questions or low-quality** and they all have the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag.

I have never had so many non-questions pop up as unanswered questions on Stack Overflow since I started using it. The names of those asking these 'questions' look fake and most of them have a reputation of 1 meaning they just created the account. One example is this non-question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77547715/what-is-python-how-python-interprator-works) another is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77547726/what-are-the-uses-of-strings-in-python). Both were posted today and have since been closed. There are many more popping up under the python tag.

Is this normal or is the system compromised in some way?

Comment: Stack Overflow has been compromised repeatedly, for some values of compromised anyway. Third parties like Charcoal tackle most of it, but that targets the hard spam. What you show here, is just nonsense and low-quality posts. Much harder to target without racking up the false positives.

Comment: Wild guess - school homework leaking into SO.

Comment: The first one is blatant chatbot output: "I am still under development".

Comment: @PM 2Ring: The origin seems to be Wikipedia and other sites. The *internal* formatting contains "wikipedia.org" and "Python logo" on ***separate lines*** (they don't render well here). And "Python interpreter diagram" and "medium.com" on ***separate lines***. Both are signatures of copying text directly off a web page. Perhaps from an AI with sources? Or direct from Wikipedia? Probably AI: *"I was expecting that my explanation would be helpful to you."*. Bing AI (or whatever it is called)?

Comment: Someone just posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548092/question-about-cloning-repositories-title-how-do-i-clone-a-github-repositor). Has nothing to do with Python but included the python tag.

Comment: There is definitely something going on: Similar post like that pop up every few minutes. Latest on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548190/please-give-me-a-proper-guideline-for-github. Although not really spam in itself, should we start flagging such posts as spam in order to help the spam detection mechanism?

Comment: 38 questions (total, without any filter) in the last 20 minutes. This is a poor counting statistics, but this corresponds to about 2700 new questions per day. The average rate for a week (incl. the weekend) is about 2500, so it is a bit high for a Saturday (at the peak in about 2014, 8000 new questions were posted on a ***weekday***, thus not entirely comparable).

Comment: It could all be selection bias (for instance, day of the week, time of day (time zones), etc.), but many of the accounts are many years old, but for many (there are exceptions) there is only ***one*** post in all those years (today). Is that expected or not?

Comment: **Please do not flag these posts as spam!** Not all moderators monitor Meta and the posts don't *look like* spam. If they reach the threshold for auto-nuking, they’d also make for very poor review audits.

Comment: @blackgreen I'm voting to close them then voting to delete, but should I also flag them for anything besides spam? I've started flagging them as "In need of moderator intervention" saying, "Possible spam, possible usage of AI. See [this question]", is that ok?

Comment: @wjandrea the best advice at this point is moderate as usual. custom mod flags are unlikely to work any better. we're already aware of the issue

Comment: *Specifically* today, or just "these days, getting worse over time"? Because I can definitely vouch for the latter. (Okay, I looked at the examples. That is indeed exceptional.)

Comment: I also noticed the rudeness in the way they demand for answers to their low-quality questions like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552758/how-we-convert-dictionary-into-tuple-sets-and-also-in-list-in-python) "I want solution of this question immediately."

Comment: @journpy that could also be a cultural/linguistical issue. A similar case is users posting a "I'm having this issue too" answer but wording it as "even I am facing this issue". That's not so much to say that they're fantastic and if *even they* are facing it, it must be a tremendously difficult problem, but rather something resulting from the translation from whatever they speak as native language.

Comment: Despite @blackgreen's efforts, I'm now seeing these pop up quite a bit, and now there are examples that have nothing to do with Python as well: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77555846.

Comment: @Adriaan That's their problem, not ours.

Comment: "I flagged [...] and they all have the [tag:python] tag" - are you just looking at that tag, or are you looking at **all** new questions?

Comment: @sehe was looking at the python tag only although I've seen some of them tag multiple languages with no relationship to what they're 'asking'

Comment: Your question would be 100% correct if you replaced "today" with "for many years now" and if you replaced "the Python tag" with "in all tags".

Comment: if you search for "flood" on MSO you get some pretty telling posts over the years. We live in a **society!**... and our society digitizes, including the schools. It's just the way it is, there are periods where people come looking for answers to the wrong questions is going to skyrocket. That does not imply that there are not other reasons why poor questions appear in floods of course, but the point is that "floods" are to be expected. So be mentally prepared for enduring them.

Comment: MAN, it really feels like recently there's a sudden spike in spammy questions. All New contributors, some accounts that haven't been used before or have at most 1 or 2 other questions, unformatted question or copy paste from somewhwere else.

Comment: @Daviid that would be the result of a flood... a sudden spike :)

Comment: Still happening; a bunch of questions from 1-rep users mostly with Indian/Subcontinental names. Mostly non-questions, e.g., short paragraphs to essays on how to do something quite elementary.

Comment: As an update, There are now posters finding old popular questions and re-posting them word for word.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586798/how-to-remove-common-keys-in-dictionary] and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77580413/how-to-remove-specific-common-keys-in-dictionary] are word for word copies of this well received older post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995611/removing-multiple-keys-from-a-dictionary-safely]

Comment: @JonSG I think it should be marked 'plagiarised' instead of duplicate

Comment: @journpy I originally flagged it as a duplicate as I searched for an found that "similar" question before someone else pointed out that it was in fact plagiarized, but I'm not sure I can alter my vote/flag at this point.

Comment: "[how we can find maximum number of element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77587216/430766)" came up today. It was originally tagged "c++ arrays dsa" despite being also about python and having zero to do with dsa. This question does **not** look like a human wrote it.

Comment: I've tried to make this user understand that questions like [Can anyone suggest website which are best for learning and practicing programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77589922/can-anyone-suggest-website-which-are-best-for-learning-and-practicing-programmin#comment136786867_77589922) aren't allowed on SO. Despite having read the tour and gained the 'Informed' badge, I doubt he actually read through it.

Comment: There are still a lot of those "questions" coming in.

Comment: @Matthias yes and there seems to be a spike during the weekends. This [history lesson non-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77595944/which-loop-is-better-in-python) was just closed.

Comment: @journpy which is basically the same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77595881/which-loop-is-better-in-python-for-loop-while-loop

Comment: Seems like the waves of posts continue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601550/how-do-we-define-an-interface-for-an-adt-or-explain-adt-interface-in-python-pro

Comment: The apparently unstoppable non-questions continue. It would be interesting to know if the same IP address is being used or if the IP locations are the same. It's a mystery what the 'contributors' get out of it.

Comment: Also another interesting thing is that it only happens on specific times and not all the day. Maybe the time they take their class?

Comment: @Puteri I noticed that. Also during the weekends.

Comment: @user19077881 some of them said they are students of 'Lovely Professional University'

Comment: I am not sure but are these questions posted by the students being used by them also as a target for them to post answers to? I see quite a lot of these attracting answers from low rep users.

Comment: Yea I've also noticed that. My guess is that could also be playing out or perhaps other low rep community members are racing to answer the questions.

Comment: This is the most ridiculous yet [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77607366/python-in-built-methods?noredirect=1). This can't be a rep-seeking attempt as they all get down-voted.

Comment: This can't be a homework assignment or something like that. I doubt university students would want bad grades unless their professor is teaching how to spam...

Comment: @user19077881: The filler text was copied directly from [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figma#History). Perhaps it was a way to get the question past some of the filters on Stack Overflow that prevents posting? [For example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251183/cannot-figure-why-am-getting-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-prop/345442#345442), *"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted"*

Comment: If anyone is watching the python tag for these, asking about an `SSLError` with Python requests is quite a common question in this wave.

Comment: They've pretty much reduced on the python tag although they still pop up here and there. Have they switched to git? Will watch the tag.

Comment: FWIW: there is a similar batch popping up [with the git tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427448/a-clue-about-git-command-is-not-returning-any-value-in-makefile-questions-on-s) (<- now moved to stackoverflow specific meta)

Comment: I have just sent a message to Dr Rajeev Sobti, Head of the Computer Science Dept at Lovely Professional University pointing out these problems. I'd like to think this will have an effect on the postings supposedly coming from that Institution.

Comment: @user19077881 seems it didn't help much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646337/the-python-student

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I [SpamRammed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/) <strike>an IP</strike> a few IPs that had quite a number of new account creations on the same day and were used to post one or more of these weird questions. This hopefully slows down the influx.

I also deleted <strike>a couple more</strike> several posts that were obviously plagiarized from random websites.

At this time there aren’t unequivocal signs that a spam/nonsense campaign is ongoing ~ or brewing. The most likely explanation is one of those programming courses that invite their students to create Stack Overflow accounts. It wouldn’t be the first occurrence.

Please keep moderating the questions as usual. **Don’t flag as spam or rude/abusive**, unless there is an obvious basis for a red flag, as the posts in isolation don’t look like red-flaggable content. Moderators who aren’t aware of the surrounding context might decline the flags.

You can use "In need of moderator intervention" flags if you find other patterns of abuse of the system such as LLM-generated content, vote fraud, ban evasion, etc., or "Plagiarized content" flags in case of plagiarism.

We're exploring alternative routes to address the issue in a more permanent way in order to alleviate the burden on our curation/moderation resources that are already stretched thin. I will post updates if/when possible.

Comment: "A plausible explanation is one of those programming courses that invite their students to create Stack Overflow accounts." - the "questions" I'm seeing look more like attempts at a miniature (and vapid) essay on some programming topic, rather than attempts at actually trying to find something out.

Comment: I think it's becoming a new spamming approach to have ChatGPT write some sort of essay on a topic (if they're good, it's both on-topic *and* looks like a question - if not, it [looks like spam](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77540861/revisions)) then sprinkle in some mention of the advertised product.

Comment: @Bergi That sounds plausible, but to me many of these sound more like an attempt to write a tutorial/self-answered-question-type post than to promote a product. It seems like the ChatGPT-essay writers aren't aware that self-answered posts still have to clearly *separate* the question and answer (answers shouldn't be posted as questions!). Like this one from the Triage queue https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/35316402 which also inexplicably links to a screenshot of the user's earned badges.

Comment: FYI: there now also seem to be AI-generated answers popping up on these questions. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77555379/5211833), where two almost identical answers were posted by new users.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck The only reason I can think of for doing that would be a voting ring of sock puppets that will be used for spamming later.

Comment: @Adriaan Another answered one has popped up in the review queue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77581169/dynamic-code-evolution-in-python-achieving-seamless-runtime-modifications Should I flag the answer as "Very Low Quality"?

Comment: It's not definitive, but I'm noticing quite a few of these "questions" are coming from users from "Lovely Professional University", like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77590718/how-to-take-input-in-python-programing-language and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77573227/2745495. They are formatted like blog posts, sharing information rather than actually asking a question.

Comment: *At this time there aren’t unequivocal signs that a spam/nonsense campaign is ongoing* - my flagging and del-vote history tells a different story. Look at these two posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77595944/which-loop-is-better-in-python) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77595881/which-loop-is-better-in-python-for-loop-while-loop) which have both the identical topic, both filled with identical nonsense text but posted by different users. continued below...

Comment: Another example are the two identical questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77595036/python-list-and-tuples) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594673/what-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-a-tuple-in-python), again same sh*t, different users....

Comment: @jps that you find a lot of stuff worthy of your close/delete votes doesn't imply there's a deliberate campaign ongoing. But I do agree that a sizeable chunk of this VLQ content seems to come from specific places. We are exploring alternative paths to address this.

Comment: @blackgreen My guess is, that many of these posts come from students of a certain institution who might have been tasked to "contribute" on SO just for the sake of posting here. Here's a quote from a comment that was posted by a user who probably is also a student at the LPU (same as mentioned by Gino Mempin above): *I did that because I was in a rush and I had to show proof that I did something in stackoverflow for an assignment* - I made similar observations to the ones mentioned by Gino Mempin.

Comment: @jps that quote is useful for making our case, do you have a link to that comment? or to the question

Comment: @blackgreen [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77594217/7329832). The user doesn't mention LPU in their profile, but VLAZ on SOCVR found a LinkedIn Profile with the same name and bio mentioning the LPU

Comment: And the continue to post identical questions under different accounts, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601757/how-a-fresher-start-his-her-journey-after-12th) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601610/how-a-fresher-start-his-her-journey-after-12th). The collection of nonsense tags is the icing on the cake.

Comment: I wonder if submitting a question that is downvoted straight through the earth and subsequently deleted counts as passing or failing the assignment?

Comment: It's hard to understand why they would make sock-puppet accounts and re-ask the question if the purpose of posting is simply to "show proof that I did something in stackoverflow". I can sort of imagine different students copy-pasting questions from each other, but at this level of nonsense, is that really any easier than asking their own question?

Comment: Is there a flag we can use for [rubbish like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77644608/design-a-python-text-game-using-oop-for-rooms-and-interactions-and-explain-brie)? Prior to the onslaught of these, they wouldn't have been flaggable (just downvote, close vote, and delete vote). But *something* is different lately, should we flag in some way to trigger more IP interventions?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the problem with flagging this kind of stuff is that it is *less* effective than the usual close/delete community-led moderation — and it would be a departure from standard practices of dealing with low quality content. We all agree that there has been a surge of this crap in recent times, and we do know that community resources are under pressure, but there's really nothing much that moderators can do more than you. IP blacklisting may help slow this down a little, but there's no guarantee that any given post you flag comes from an IP that's worth banning.

Comment: @blackgreen - Thanks. I suspected as much. It's just I see people commenting about flagging them (including on that one) and I think "Can we? Which flag? Will it help, or just cause more mod work?" Sounds like the answer is it would just cause more mod work without helping.

Comment: Please let me know if I'm wrong on this, Is it just me or is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77715335/number-tiles-fifteen-board-game#comment137011097_77715335 meant to have the python tag? I've flagged since yesterday and I seem to be the only one that spotted it. The syntax is not python and also the question needs more focus.

Comment: @journpy That's definitely JavaScript and not Python, so it shouldn't have the Python tag at all. Since the programming language tag is what determines syntax highlighting, and Python doesn't have `var` or `function` keywords (while JS does), this means that `var` and `function` are not being correctly highlighted in the code from the question.