# SO getting bombarded with Pascal's triangle

Tags: discussion

Today SO is bombarded with so many low-quality, zero effort questions.

Primarily about [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) in Python.

I suspect we have semesters in this part of the world (India).

Here are the links:

[pascal_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601391/how-to-create-a-pascal-triangle-in-python)

[pascal_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601382/pascal-triangle-with-user-input)

[pascal_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599459/how-to-print-the-pascals-triangle-in-python)

[pascal_4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599243/pascal-triangle-in-python)

[pascal_5_deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599513/how-to-create-pascal-traingle-in-python?noredirect=1#comment136803539_77599513)

Comment: meh, only 6 so far

Comment: haha!.. let see we may get more

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat.. I think these users are different instead of a same person creating different IDs.. These students may be in the same class getting their semester assignment.

Comment: The triangle one is usually a problem at this time of the year anyway. I think a lot of teaching institutions use it to demonstrate simple loops and logic. The questions are often closeable as too broad. Although it might be a good idea to have some sort of reference for all of them that goes over the principles, not needing any code. This can even be language agnostic. Related: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Yes they're probably not a single user, it seems they are from "Lovely Professional University" as per [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427302/recent-flood-of-very-low-quality-questions-and-non-questions-with-the-python-tag#comment979674_427307)

Comment: Yup... now it makes sense.. you got it right @Abdul!

Comment: I'm seeing a ton of complete garbage this last hour.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk.. absolutely you are right!!!

Comment: Only the last hour?

Comment: I don't think these are related to the other post. The other ones had some ChatGPT hallmarks; these seem more like nonsense from people who have barely any idea what to ask and struggle with English.

Comment: Why don't they search? [It isn't exactly scarce on Stack Overflow](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Pascal%27s%20triangle%20Python).

Comment: [Golfed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242073/code-golf-generate-pascals-triangle/1242311#1242311): `def G(n):R=[[1]];exec"R+=[map(sum,zip(R[-1]+[0],[0]+R[-1]))];"*~-n;return R`

Comment: We are getting more and more low quality, zero effort questions today as well.

Comment: @PeterMortensen apparently they have an assignment to [do something on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427302/recent-flood-of-very-low-quality-questions-and-non-questions-with-the-python-tag#comment979781_427307)

Comment: If the grader wants to be helpful, that Do Something would be to get the informed badge.

Comment: Just more proof that people really, really, really do not know what Stack Overflow is and nothing changes that state. It remains a site "to ask questions on". If we're lucky it is understood that they need to be programming-related at least, but the further nuances of "how this is not Reddit" are just completely lost on people.