# Is there a new template based tool for helping to ask questions?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

This morning I have run into several questions that seem to use some kind of templating system to help users ask questions.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77608008/issue-with-specific-technology-tool-brief-description-of-the-problem **(apparently a raw template)**
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77613673/difficulty-generating-unique-random-numbers-using-pythons-random-module has a block *"[describe the specific problem or error]"*
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77613588/optimizing-python-code-for-efficient-handling-of-large-datasets-minimizing-memo has several blocks in it like *[describe your dataset, e.g., CSV files, database records]*
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77613500/how-can-i-efficiently-handle-large-datasets-in-python-without-running-into-memor *[brief description of dataset]*
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77613499/how-can-i-efficiently-handle-large-datasets-in-python-without-running-into-memor (exact duplicate of prior item)

With the recent influx of low quality questions that look bot driven:

- [New users posting spam with links in Collective discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427394/new-users-posting-spam-with-links-in-collective-discussions)
- [Recent flood of very low quality questions and non-questions with the Python tag today - what is going on?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427302/recent-flood-of-very-low-quality-questions-and-non-questions-with-the-python-tag)

I want to make sure I understand how to interpret these incomplete templated questions correctly. If they are a SO feature to help new users ask questions that I am not aware of then that is great. Any help to get people to ask good questions is welcomed by me. On the other hand, if this is a 3rd party template system that is the next evolution in bot spamming SO to say potentially farm rep then I would like to know that as part of responding or ignoring or voting to close.

Comment: No, there's no new template tool. You're looking at [students from Lovely Professional University](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427302/recent-flood-of-very-low-quality-questions-and-non-questions-with-the-python-tag#comment979674_427307) posting a flood of questions...

Comment: One of them even directly posted the template: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77608008/issue-with-specific-technology-tool-brief-description-of-the-problem

Comment: Long story short: the Python tag bites right now.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, this kind of thing is cutting into my desire to even review questions in the python tag.

Comment: [I <expletive>ing _wish_ people in my tags would be guided to give this level of info in their questions](/q/424638/#comment957404_424644).

Comment: Looks like it's not just students - stumbled over [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77618575/seeking-assistance-for-performance-issues-on-dog-insurance-website) using a similarly template-y setup ("particularly when users [mention any specific actions, like loading pages or submitting forms]") where the point seemed to be "look at my dog insurance website".

Comment: Glad to see that all of those questions have been Meta effect'd.

Comment: in case anyone is interested, here are users (likely) from that "Lovely Professional University": https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1808275/lpu-users (as up-to-date as SEDE is)

Comment: Apparently they also use a template for their profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/22989646/rudra-tiwari

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm generally aware of any official projects that SE is launching or planning to launch, especially since I'm paying attention to the mod team. Nothing like this was announced, so I highly doubt this is related to SE. There are two possibilities remaining:

1. A person created templates for these users to use while asking SO questions. Maybe it was their teacher.
2. An AI created the templates. For example, I once gave ChatGPT a short prompt asking it to write a letter on my behalf. I mentioned the purpose of the letter but did not give very any details beyond that. As a result, the output had placeholders in brackets peppered throughout the text:

   > My expertise in [mention relevant experience or qualifications] has equipped me with the necessary skills to navigate the challenges and opportunities in the tech sector.

   There seems to be some variation in the templates in these SO questions, and the grammar is of the exact quality that one would expect from an AI, so I think this option is more likely than the former. We also have evidence that users are using gen AI to create bad questions in [Recent flood of very low quality questions and non-questions with the Python tag today - what is going on?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427302/6083675) (these events are likely related).

   In practice, given the lack of quality of these half-templated questions, it doesn't really matter either way.

Note: Not all the questions are tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). I added the tag to some that only had [python-asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-asyncio).

Comment: I *just* saw a [tag:javascript] question that stated that they were required to submit a question to SO for some course. (It didn't have anything substantive in it.) Unfortunately, it was deleted before I could get the link for it...

Answer (score 16):

While we haven't aggressively pursued AI-*assisted* questions, it's long been my suspicion that some of the questions are *purely* written by AI, possibly for future SEO or other Spam purposes.

If you prompt ChatGPT with:

> Write an example question for Stack Overflow about Python

It won't take many re-generations to get a question similar to many of the ones you've run across today.  My 6th regen of that prompt resulted in:

> How can I efficiently parse a large CSV file in Python and store specific columns in a dictionary?

I've seen an almost identical question used as part of a sock-puppet scheme as well.

As @Laurel said, these questions are often fairly bad in the first place, and either voted down, closed, or don't receive any answers anyway.  That doesn't stop the SEO-"bots" from trying.  What you are seeing today *seems* to be an evolution of the past questions, where the user/bot/spammer is trialing some type of templating system for their questions.

I'd caution, however, against assuming that every low-quality "efficient" question is AI-generated.  When you see dead-giveaways like these templates, that's one thing, but otherwise, we (reminder to self, as well) need to remember that there *can* be real new users these who are asking a legitimate question.

Comment: Have I totally missunderstood this: ["_All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.
This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers._"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) ..?

Comment: @Teemu Fair enough - I figured someone would bring that up ;-).  I was thinking that there was another post somewhere mentioning the "relaxed" version of it, but I can't find it, so I've modified the wording.  It's true that the policy there says that everything except for profiles is disallowed.  We've tended to not focus on the questions which are AI-assisted, unless they are problematic in other ways, but technically, yes, that's against the rules as well.