# A clue about "git command is not returning any value in makefile" questions on SO?

Tags: discussion, spam

There was a question asked in January 2023:

[git command not returning any value in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75016345/git-command-not-returning-any-value-in-makefile)

which was duplicated (as in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, spotted by an SO user) in November:

[Git command is not returning any value in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548335/git-command-is-not-returning-any-value-in-makefile)

And recently a sequence of questions mentioned the exact same issue (variations in wording, looking like the question was handwritten each time).

All the following questions date from the last two days (between December 6th and 8th 2023):

- [Git command is returning any value in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77619063/git-command-is-returning-any-value-in-makefile)
- [Git command is not returning any value in makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77625179/git-command-is-not-returning-any-value-in-makefile)
- [git command is not working any value in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77606667/git-command-is-not-working-any-value-in-makefile)
- [Git command is not returning any value in makefolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77619688/git-command-is-not-returning-any-value-in-makefolder)
- [Git command is not returning value in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614598/git-command-is-not-returning-value-in-makefile)
- [Git Command is not returning any value in makefile what to do now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614005/git-command-is-not-returning-any-value-in-makefile-what-to-do-now)

That one got deleted:

- [Git command is not returning any value in makefil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77625054/git-command-is-not-returning-any-value-in-makefil)

---

I fail to see a purpose (good or evil), or a common trigger.

Has anyone got a clue about why this batch of questions popped all of a sudden on Stack Overflow?

---

The questions listed above have been closed and deleted since this post was created; let's see if something happens next!

Comment: user VLAZ originally pointed me to this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427302/recent-flood-of-very-low-quality-questions-and-non-questions-with-the-python-tag

Comment: At least one of the questioners says they are attending LPU, so probably more poor quality stuff from them.

Comment: [Git command is not returning any value in makefolder \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77619688/git-command-is-not-returning-any-value-in-makefolder) is generated (at least partially) by CrapGPT; there is **very** tell tail detail in there.

Comment: If *only* the staging ground were live... Then none of these questions would ever get out of it.

Comment: @ThomA If only [Triage actually prevented questions from being displayed elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374881/triage-implementation-has-been-silently-abandoned-midway-how-bad-is-that).

Comment: What a funny tags are used for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77606667/git-command-is-not-working-any-value-in-makefile): [tag:nlp-question-answering], [tag:fabric-answers]. Such are honest LLM has generated them.

Comment: LPU = *[Lovely Professional University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovely_Professional_University)*. *"Lovely Professional University (LPU) is a private university located in Chaheru, [Phagwara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phagwara), [Punjab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punjab,_India), India. The university was established in 2005 by Lovely International Trust, through the Lovely Professional University Act, 2005 (Punjab Act 25 of 2005) and started operation in 2006."*

Comment: Perhaps they copied the homework assignment information from the same PDF document in which [the TAB character](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=8m49s) ***[required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29#Rules)*** for [Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) to work properly didn't survive (e.g., was converted to [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The consensus seems to be:

- yes, these questions are low quality
- some of them have indications the question itself had its content generated
  (as noted by user@ThomA: question [77619688](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77619688/git-command-is-not-returning-any-value-in-makefolder) contains for example "I'm using Git version X.X.X on an OS Y.Y.Y.")

It hasn't been established whether this batch of questions has been entirely generated by a bot (profiles included), or if they come from actual people with a common drive (for example: a badly worded assignment at a CS formation ?).

---

There are several other known occurrences of low quality questions with common features popping on SO. See for example:
[Recent flood of very low quality questions and non-questions with the Python tag today - what is going on?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427302/recent-flood-of-very-low-quality-questions-and-non-questions-with-the-python-tag)

It looks like this "Git command is not returning value in makefile" surge is over for now, and all the existing ones have been moderated (as in: closed and deleted by the community). There isn't much more to do at the moment.